# JPA LOJ (left outer join) : Cannot join to attribute of basic type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities I want to do an LOJ on using JPA and a criteria query.  Sounds easy enough but I am running into a problem.  My entities:

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1")
public class Table1 {
       @Id
       @SuppressWarnings("all")
       @Column(name = "ROWID")
        private String rowId;

       @Column(name = "SOME_ID")
       private String someId;
       ....
       @ManyToMany
       @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ID", referencedColumnName = "SOME_ID")
       private List<Table2> table2s;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2")
public class Table2 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    @Column(name = "ROWID")
    private String rowId;

   @Column(name = "SOME_ID")
    private String someIdAsId;
   ....

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "table2s")
   private List<Table1> table1s;
}
```

My criteria query/join:

```
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery();
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        Root<Table1> previewSearch = criteriaQuery.from(Table1.class);

        if(searchFields.contains(A_FILE)) {
            Join<Table1, Table2> join = previewSearch.join("someId", JoinType.LEFT);
        }
```

Later I add a filter criteria for reg file, as in:

```
predicates.add(cb.like(cb.trim(cb.lower((previewSearch.get("aFileNo")))), "%" + legacySearchCriteria.getAFileNo() + "%"));
```

then add the preds to the query:

```
criteriaQuery.select(previewSearch).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

then:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Table1> results = getResults(query);
```

The code around the getting of results and all is proven.  That isn't the issue.  It has something to do with the way I have my entities annotated or similar.  When I run the query when I have the "AFile" in the query (triggering the creation of a Join object in my code), I get a stacktrace whose base error is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.constructJoin(AbstractFromImpl.java:254)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:247)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:422)
at com.xxx.ent.dataobjects.common.dao.SearchDao.executeQuery(PreviewConditionalSearchDao.java:77)
at com.xxx.ent.dataobjects.common.dao.SearchDao.getPreview(PreviewConditionalSearchDao.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I have hit this site et al. and nothing there looks like it has a fix for me, though I tried several things.  Anyone have ideas?

---- UPDATE ----

In essence I was looking to do a:

```
select fields from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.f1=t2.f1 where t2.f2 = 'somevalue'
```

Lessons learned: f1 must be the Id column of the JPA entities being joined or else you don't get it.  The final answer looks like this:

Entities:

```
 @Data
 @ToString
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "TABLE_1")
 public class Table1 {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private String id;
 ....
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Table2 table2;
 }
```

and

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_2")
public class Table2 {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "ID")
 private String id;

 @Column(name = "FIELD_2")
 private String f2;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "table2")
 private List<Table1> table1s;
}
```

Code:

```
EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery();
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
Root<Table1> table1Root = criteriaQuery.from(Table1.class);
Path field2Path = null;

if(searchFields.contains(FIELD2)) {
   Join<Table1, Table2> field2Join = table1Root.join("table2", JoinType.LEFT);
    field2Path = field2Join.get("f2");
}

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

// add preds ...
case SOME_PRED:              
  predicates.add(cb.like(cb.trim(cb.lower((table1Root.get("somePred")))), "%" + criteria.getSomePred() + "%"));
  break;
case FIELD2:
  predicates.add(cb.like(cb.trim(cb.lower((field2Path))), "%" + criteria.getField2() + "%"));
  break;

....
criteriaQuery.select(table1Root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

Then run the query.  That actuallly works.  Finally.

Answer (score 1):

A join forms an aggregate of two entity types, yielding entity tuples.  You are expected to designate an attribute identifying the relationship characterizing the join, not the join column.  Something like this:

```
        Join<Table1, Table2> join = previewSearch.join("table2s", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I changed it to as you suggested but what I am doing here is a left join between two tables wherein a value in the joined table is part of the filter criteria, so it's more like: select fields from Table1 left outer join Table2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.f2 = 'value' and .... (other criteria).  Now I am finding if I add a second root to the query I ghet a crossjoin back from the translator, which I don't need.  Otherwise it doesn't recognize t2.f2 in my criteria.

Comment: @MattCampbell, if a property of the right entity is used in a filter criterion, and the predicate for it is other than `IS NULL`, then you are actually going a long way around to an *inner* join.

Comment: In any case, I'm uncertain what you hope I will do with your comment.  The answer already explains the nature of the JPA error you asked about, and what is expected instead.  If you have a followup question about other aspects of the query or the larger program containing it then that would be best posed as a new question.

Comment: Your initial reply essentially cleared up that issue.  But  I had to create two new JPA entities for the tables in question with @ Id set to the fields I wanted to join on.  I also had to use the Join object I created to reference the field I was filtering on in the joined table to get rid of the second Root reference that was creating the cross join.  Also I had to mark in Table1 the @ JoinColumn with insertable=false, updatable=false to avoid a dupe field ref, and set the fetch to FetchType.LAZY in the @ ManyToOne annotation to avoid a Hibernate startup error.